# how to reduce the database's pressure

Tags: linq, sql-server-2005

I have a database(sql server 2005),now there are about 100000 records in the table called users, when I do query use linq to sql, it is very slower and slower.how can I do some operate to improve the speed?

Comment: Show us SQL query and table structure (indexes at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (in order of preference)

- Save your query as a stored procedure
- Add indexes to your users
  table, for what you are querying for/sorting for
- Analyze your query
  (if it is complicated), see if there's a less-resource-intensive way
  of doing it.  There are graphical query analyzers to help you.
- As a last resort, not use LINQ, but instead ADO.NET Entity Framework, it's significantly faster.  But you'll only see performance improvements for crazy stuff, and only if you've already done all of the above.

Comment: In fact, you should always do the first two, unless your query is stupid simple (select * from users).  In that case a stored procedure probably won't help, but you should pretty much always add indexes to fields that you'll be searching over, as long as they contain largely different, non-null values. (If there's a lot of duplicates, test, because an index might actually be slower).

Answer (score 2):

Analyse your query and add some indexes to your table may help.

To get a more specific answer post more specific information (table stucture, indexes you have, the sql code L2S generates, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Use stored procedures and then use linq to sql to get the desired rows, this will give performance.

Answer (score 0):

The best tools at your disposal for analyzing your database access and seeing what needs to be optimized are:

- [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)
- [Graphical Execution Plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

The first one will allow you to see the exact queries being sent to your database from your application, which is especially useful if it turns out that your application is chattier than you think.  The second one will allow you to take those queries and see exactly what the SQL server is doing with them.

In the graphical execution plan, look for steps which use a lot of CPU and paths which transfer a lot of records.  Those are what you'll want to optimize.  It's possible that you're doing a table scan somewhere, which is slow, or maybe joining on many more records than you need somewhere, which is slow, etc.